# How to force RPART to fit data exactly in R

Tags: r, graphics, data-fitting, rpart

It happens that I need a tree that exactly fits the input data, i.e.
there should be no pruning.  In the TREE package of R, under tree.control, it
says:  "To produce a tree that fits the data perfectly, 
   set mindev = 0 and minsize = 2".
This works for me, but I would rather use the RPART R package, mostly because it is associated with nicer graphics written by Stephen Miborrow.  But I can't find a statement in the RPART documentation about how to produce a tree that fits the data perfectly.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the way to do this is:

```
rpart.control(minsplit=2,minbucket=1,cp=0)
```